# Conditional duplicate filtering query

Tags: sql, oracle

At Oracle I would like to filter below TABLE as

| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 20 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 8 | AAA | SECONDARY |
| 7 | AAA | SECONDARY |
| 7 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 8 | AAA | SECONDARY |
| 9 | AAA | SECONDARY |

my expected output is

| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 20 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 7 | AAA | PRIMARY |
| 9 | AAA | SECONDARY |

Logic is Group by COLUMNA and COLUMNB (please evaluate below conditions on grouping.)

- if columnc candidate record (grouped by `COLUMNA` and `COLUMNB`) includes only `PRIMARY` take `PRIMARY`.
- if columnc candidate record (grouped by `COLUMNA` and `COLUMNB`) includes only `SECONDARY` take `SECONDARY`.
- if columnc candidate records (grouped by `COLUMNA` and `COLUMNB`) include `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` set, take `PRIMARY`.
- if columnc candidate records (grouped by `COLUMNA` and `COLUMNB`) include duplicate `SECONDARY` set skip record.
- imagine this row has 100 columns so I need to fetch row by itself. MAX MIN wont work here.

I have used couple of `row_number()` functions and `where not exist`s but went into oblivion.

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Comment: Why is 9 in the result set?

Comment: edited condition. Because it has to be there. If only secondary I have with the column, it should be included @GordonLinoff

Comment: The `COLUMNA` 8 value has 2 `SECONDARY` and it's not on your expected output. Are you clear on what you want? Why do you say the logic is un `COLUMNA` and `COLUMNB` if `COLUMNB` always have the same value?

Comment: yes @JaimeDrq. I dont need that rows, it has to be skipped. Because I dont have candidate for primary there and double `secondary` is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CInspired by @Jaime Drq have solution below.
Easy to understand and optimized query.

```sql
WITH TABLE_VIEW AS (
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNA, COLUMNB ORDER BY COLUMNC ASC) CANDIDATERANKING
    FROM TABLE)
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, SUM(CANDIDATERANKING) PRIORITY
            FROM TABLE_VIEW TT
          GROUP BY COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC)
    WHERE PRIORITY= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this query is what you are looking for. As I said in my comment, 8 should be also included based on your description

```
with your_data as (
  select 19 as columna, 'AAA' as columnb, 'PRIMARY' as columnc from dual union all
  select 20,'AAA','PRIMARY' from dual union all
  select 8 ,'AAA','SECONDARY' from dual union all
  select 7 ,'AAA','SECONDARY' from dual union all
  select 7 ,'AAA','PRIMARY' from dual union all
  select 8 ,'AAA','SECONDARY' from dual union all
  select 9 ,'AAA','SECONDARY' from dual
)
select distinct COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC
from (
  select 
    COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, 
    count(DISTINCT COLUMNC) over (partition by COLUMNA) as x,
    count(COLUMNC) over (partition by COLUMNA) as y
  from your_data
  ) yd
where
  -- if columnc candidate rows includes only PRIMARY take PRIMARY
  (COLUMNC = 'PRIMARY' and x = 1)
  or
  -- if columnc candidate rows includes only SECONDARY take SECONDARY (just one record)
  (COLUMNC = 'SECONDARY' and x = 1 and y=1)
  or
  -- if columnc candidate rows includes PRIMARY and SECONDARY take PRIMARY
  (COLUMNC = 'PRIMARY' and x = 2)
order by 1
```

Comment: `if columnc candidate rows includes duplicate SECONDARY set skip record.`

Again 8 shouldnt be included, because `COLUMNA` `8` candidates always have `SECONDARY` in `COLUMNC`

Comment: And why 9 yes then?

Comment: because 9 is single record. `SECONDARY` included if have single record. But it duplicates or triplicates, it has to be skipped.

Comment: I have modified the query, does it meet your goal now? Maybe you can simplify it, but I keep it this way to show each filter related to your description

Comment: Matured by some special reason? Do you understand it?

Comment: why wouldnt I :) Just observing to find out alternate ways. I upped your answer.

Comment: No no... Don't misuderstand me... I just was saying if you need some explanation I could give it to you. Not sure if there are many other ways easier than this one to solve your query, it's quite tricky.

Comment: yes I got the logic behind your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like aggregation does what you want:

```
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, MIN(COLUMNC)
FROM t
GROUP BY COLUMNA, COLUMNB
HAVING MIN(COLUMNC) = 'PRIMARY';
```

Actually, based on your logic (but not the results which are inconsistent), `WHERE` is sufficient:

```
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, MIN(COLUMNC)
FROM t
WHERE COLUMNC = 'PRIMARY'
GROUP BY COLUMNA, COLUMNB;
```

Or for the entire row:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2 ORDER BY Column1) as seqnum
      FROM t
      WHERE COLUMNC = 'PRIMARY'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin . . . That just requires a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: imagine this row has 100 columns so I need to fetch row by itself. MAX MIN wont work here.

I need entire row. Now 3 columns... I can make min to all 98 columns.